# rollapply in xts run out of memory R

Tags: r, apply, xts, zoo

i have an `xts` object which is about 2 mil rows.  i am trying to use `rollapply` with `width=10000`.  rollapply seems to run out of memory and i am having trouble figuring out why? (i tried to look at the source by typing `> rollapply` but only this shows up:

```
function (data, ...) 
 UseMethod("rollapply")
 <environment: namespace:zoo>
```

does rollapply create 2 million - 10,000 copies of each chunk and then pass them in one by one? this would certainly cause it to run out of memory but i don't think the creators of `zoo` would have done that? if that is the case, then does anyone know a more clever way to do my rolling apply.. my current plan is to simply do this:

```
m <- vector()
for (i in 10001:nrow(my_xts)) {
   m <- c(m, my_fun(my_xts[i-10000:i]))

}
```

sure there is a better way?

Comment: Your current plan makes the cardinal sin of growing an object in a loop.  You need to pre-allocate your result before the loop and insert each function's result in the i-th element of the result vector.

Comment: The zoo package does have optimized (for speed not memory) `rollmean`, `rollmax` and `rollmedian`if your function corresponds to one of those but it might be that some or all of them use less memory too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the memory consumption is occurring during the `mapply` call in `zoo:::rollapply.zoo`.  There is an xts `rollapply` method but it is not exported, so it will not be called via method dispatch.  That said, you can call it explicitly:

```
my_xts <- .xts(1:1e5*1,1:1e5)
m <- xts:::rollapply.xts(my_xts, width=10000, FUN=sum)
```

Use `methods(foo)` to see what methods are available whenever you encounter:

```
function(...)
  UseMethod("foo")
```

Comment: how do you actually look at the source? so for `rollapply.zoo` it's `zoo:::rollapply.zoo` but how would i know that just from doing `methods(rollapply)`?

Comment: also, why is the `xts::rollapply.xts` not exported? just wondering if there are bugs in it still to be worked out.

Comment: @Alex: `methods(rollapply)` shows the methods and notes: "Non-visible functions are asterisked".  That means they're not exported and you have to use the `package:::` syntax.  `rollapply.xts` is not exported because we wrote it quickly and didn't to much testing at the time.  It could probably be exported now though.  It's on my to-do list.